# How to always end a slice at a certain value

Tags: python, byte, slice

I am dealing with a number of different length byte objects.  However, they will all contain a certain `byte` that I want to end on (i.e. I will always want to get a certain number of values up to that value but not past it).  The problem is it is not always the last byte (so I can't just use `[:-1]`. I am never interested in what comes after that so it is okay for me to ignore what comes later but I do need to capture what comes before it.

Is there a way in Python to slice up to a certain **value** as opposed to a certain index?

i.e.

```
[2:'\xf0']
```

to slice from the third byte to the `\xf0` byte?

Comment: Not in a slice, you will have to find the index of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.x, you can use the `index` function and slicing, like this

```
a = bytearray(b"abcd\xf0asda")
print a[2:a.index('\xf0')]
# cd
```

In Python 3.x, you just need to search with the `bytes` object, like this

```
a = b"abcd\xf0asda"
print(a[2:a.index(b'\xf0')])
# b'cd'
```

The `index` function will return the index of the item you are looking for, in the object. Beware, it will raise an exception if the item being searched for is not found in the object.